# How to convert specific format of date to useful and readable format of date in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, date

I have DataFrame in Pandas like below:

DATA TYPES:

- ID - numeric
- HOLIDAY - object
- YEAR - object

  | ID | HOLIDAY | YEAR |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 111 | 1 sty | 2022 |
  | 222 | 20 kwi | 2022 |
  | 333 | 8 mar | 2022 |
  | ... | ... | ... |
- sty - January
- kwi - APril
- mar - March

And I need to convert above table so as to have full and useful date (as string format).

So, I need to have something like below:

```
ID  | HOLIDAY     | YEAR
----|-------------|-------
111 | 01-01-2022  | 2022
222 | 20-02-2022  | 2022
333 | 08-03-2022  | 2022
... | ...         | ...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

I used somethink like that:

```
df['HOLIDAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HOLIDAY'] +" "+ df['YEAR'] , format='%d %b %Y')
df['HOLIDAY'] = df['HOLIDAY'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

but it generate error like the follow: `ValueError: time data '1 sty 2022' does not match format '%d %b %Y' (match)`

Comment: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str, use  my answer it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use this:

```
d={'sty':'-1','kwi':'-4','mar':'-3'} #creat dict 

a=df.HOLIDAY.tolist() # creat list of original holiday
for i in range(len(df)):
    for word, replacement in d.items():
        a[i] = a[i].replace(word, replacement)# creat a loop that replace the mount by her number
        a[i] = a[i].replace(" ", "")# delete the space ex '1 sty' -> '1sty'
df.HOLIDAY=a
l=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    l.append(str(df.HOLIDAY[i])+'-'+str(df.YEAR[i]))#loop that concatenat year and holiday

df.HOLIDAY=l# replace holiday in df by new values

df.HOLIDAY=pd.to_datetime(df.HOLIDAY, format="%d-%m-%Y")#transform holiday from str to datetime
```

Comment: phoenix I have error like that: KeyError: 1

Comment: can you share example for your dataframe be cause it work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["HOLIDAY"] = df["HOLIDAY"].apply(
    lambda x: x.replace("sty", "January")
    .replace("kwi", "April")
    .replace("mar", "March")
)

df["HOLIDAY"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["HOLIDAY"] + " " + df["YEAR"].astype(str)
).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID     HOLIDAY  YEAR
0  111  01-01-2022  2022
1  222  20-04-2022  2022
2  333  08-03-2022  2022
```